# Remover seta do "select"

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

***Código:***

```
<select class="backcolorselect" id="st" name="">
    <option class="backcolorselect" value="Sim">Sim</option>
    <option class="backcolorselect" value="Não">Não</option>
</select>
```

Preciso remover a seta que aponta para baixo do select, alguma ajuda em ***CSS*** ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto usando o Framework Zurb Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma solução para retirar a seta usando o **Foundation**.

Dentro do arquivo ***foundation.css***, comentei a linha `background-image`, e adicionei `-webkit-appearance: none !important;`

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  /*background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeD0iMTJweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjRweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzcHgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2IDMiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDYgMyIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+PHBvbHlnb24gcG9pbnRzPSI1Ljk5MiwwIDIuOTkyLDMgLTAuMDA4LDAgIi8+PC9zdmc+);*/
  background-position: 100% center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 2.3125rem; 
}
```

Comment: Essa solução não funcionou no IE11

Answer (score 4):

*Veja Funcionando:*

```css
    select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      text-indent: 1px;
      text-overflow: '';
    }
```

```html
<select class="backcolorselect" id="st" name="">
    <option class="backcolorselect" value="Sim">Sim</option>
    <option class="backcolorselect" value="Não">Não</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No IE também não funciona, acho que seria interessante adicionar em quais navegadores este código funciona.

Comment: Essa solução não funcionou no IE11

Answer (score 3):

Como dito pelo [@David nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134319/remover-seta-select#comment278243_134319) você pode usar jQuery para isso, vendo que somente com CSS você teria alguns problemas em relação aos diversos browsers existentes.

Ficaria assim um exemplo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
    var widthOfSelect = $("#select").width();
    widthOfSelect = widthOfSelect - 13;
    //alert(widthOfSelect);
    jQuery('#select').wrap("<div id='sss' style='width: "+widthOfSelect+"px; overflow: hidden; border-right: #000 1px solid;' width=20></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
    <option class="backcolorselect" value="Sim">Sim</option>
    <option class="backcolorselect" value="Não">Não</option>
</select>
```

Caso queira mais opções, deixarei abaixo o link da pergunta no SOen.

[Select removing dropdown arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16603979/4843158)

Comment: Essa solução não funcionou no IE11